# What is overlay in android?

Tags: android, overlay

I know how to use `Overlay` in `Android applications` i used it plenty of times.

But now i am wondering what actually meaning of the Keyword `overlay` in general terms.

one basic definition is

```
Overlay is the individual items placed on the map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, names to Classes, keywords are given in context of their real meaning. The dictionary meaning of overlay is:

> Cover the surface of (a thing) with a coating: "their fingernails were overlaid with gold".

The same applies to Android. And like you said:

> Overlay is the individual items placed on the map

Answer (score 0):

generally used to show image top of a map like pin on the map surface

[Demo Link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)
[API link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay)